# Filter ignoring accents android

Tags: android, sqlite, filter

I need to do a search in the database, I have a search but did not know how to ignore the accents in the query. Any way to configure the database to ignore in search?

Comment: add extra column with all accented characters changed to simple ascii characrers

Comment: You can leave the answer to mark it, thank you very much